# JavaFx: Static fields

Tags: javafx, static

Could you explain me why eclipse want getMissionFromMissionController() to be static if i haven't annotated listView with the static word ?
Whenever i want to create this function i've got an error:
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getMissionFromMissionController() from the type MainController"

LogPanelController:

```
public void printLog()
{
    textLog.appendText(MainController.getMissionFromMissionController());
}
```

MainController:

```
public  String getMissionFromMissionController() {

    return MissionController.listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
}
```

And the Missionontroller fields:

```
@FXML private MainController mainController;

@FXML private Label missionsLabel;
@FXML public ListView<String> listView;
@FXML private TextArea textArea;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the problems:

```
return MissionController.listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

You access the `listView` field as though it's static, and it's not - mind the upper case letter in the word MissionController, in this case you access a class, not the `missionController` field, which I guess you implied.

And the second one: you call non static method as though it's static:

```
textLog.appendText(MainController.getMissionFromMissionController());
```

Mind the upper case letter of the MainController in this line. It should be a small one, if you probably try to access the field.

Comment: @Michael Great :) Please, upvote (the up arrow button) and accept this answer (the check mark button) if it helped.